# strange error in haskell about indentation of if-then-else

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, indentation

I have the following code:

```
foo :: Int -> [String] -> [(FilePath, Integer)] -> IO Int
foo _ [] _ = return 4
foo _ _ [] = return 5
foo n nameREs pretendentFilesWithSizes = do
  result <- (bar n (head nameREs) pretendentFilesWithSizes)
  if result == 0
  then return 0 --  <========================================== here is the error
  else foo n (tail nameREs) pretendentFilesWithSizes
```

I get an error on the line with the comment above, the error is:

```
aaa.hs:56:2:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation)
```

I'm working with emacs, there's no spaces, and i do not understand what did i do wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indent `then` and `else` lines one level more. However things may change [Conditionals and `do`-notation](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/DoAndIfThenElse).

Answer (score 11):

This is explained in the "`if`-within-`do`" section of the [Wikibooks article](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation#if_within_do) on Haskell indentation.

The problem is that to the `do`-desugarer, the `then` and `else` lines look like new statements:

```
do { first thing
   ; if condition
   ; then foo
   ; else bar
   ; third thing }
```

Indenting the `then` and `else` lines will solve the problem.

**UPDATE:** Since this is tagged `beginner`, I'll also note that something like the following would generally be considered more idiomatic in Haskell:

```
foo :: Int -> [String] -> [(FilePath, Integer)] -> IO Int
foo _ [] _ = return 4
foo _ _ [] = return 5
foo n (r:rs) filesWithSizes = bar n r filesWithSizes >>= checkZero
  where
    checkZero :: Int -> IO Int
    checkZero 0 = return 0
    checkZero _ = foo n rs filesWithSizes
```

This does exactly the same thing as your `foo`, but it avoids the `do` sugar and uses pattern matching instead of `head` and `tail` and the `if-then-else` control structure. Informally, the `>>=` here says "take the output of `bar...` out of its `IO` wrapper and run it through `checkZero`, returning the result".